# GraphQL Fragments error on export to query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, recompose

### So I have a reactjs app using **GraphQl** and I'm trying to cut down the repetition through the use of **fragments**, however, its failing.

**Fragment** (companyQueries.js)

```
export const CompanyFragment = gql`
  fragment company on WithApiKeys {
    company {
      id
      apiKeys {
        id
        token
        insertedAt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**Beginning of usage** (withCreateApiKeyMutation.js)

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import CompanyFragment from '../../../utils/QueryFragments/companyQueries'

console.log(CompanyFragment)
const QUERY = gql`
  query {
    viewer {
      id
      ...company
    }
  }
  ${CompanyFragment}
```

---

### Given this kind of export I would expect it to at least be able to compile, but it errors.

**Error given by compiler**

Error on line 3 of **companyQueries.js**

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>
> export const CompanyFragment = gql <--line 3

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaUkN.png)

If anyone could provide an insight on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did not import or imported the wrong `gql`. In the last year the API was changed quite a bit.

You should not import it like

`import { gql } from 'react-apollo';`

but from this package

`import gql from 'graphql-tag';`

Comment: Bless your soul. I have like a million fragments ready and none worked